# NEO-6M GPS inaccurate by 30 miles

Tags: gps

I have a Ublox NEO-6M and NEO-N8M, both ordered from China (possibly foreshadowing?).

When I wired the N8M up, it gave me a location in the middle of a lake 30 miles away. For context, I am in South Africa in the southern hemisphere.
I drove around logging two other locations, assuming it could be calibrated with a fixed point error by getting a fixed location reading and subtracting the real coordinates, and using that offset in future calculations.

It didn't work, the inaccuracy was too great, however a lot better, but obviously, it was not the solution.

I then used the 6M. To my absolute surprise, it gave me the exact same location as the first module, exactly in the middle of that same lake. So at this point, I'm starting to wonder, could this be related to the hemisphere? Is it the fact that it could be counterfeit?

The N8M used $GNGLL and the 6M used $GPGLL so I doubt it's a discrepancy with the GPS and GLONASS systems.

Any help would be appreciated, all I want is a really accurate fix on my location.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Excuse me, but what does this have to do with programming? Stack Overflow requires questions to have _something_ to do with programming.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled the same way (~30 miles away) until re-reading the NMEA Protocol and realising that it was my fault. So maybe this may help you as well:

The format in the sentence for lat is ddmm.mmmm and for lon it is dddmm.mmmm so you have to do some calculations on your own:

Separate the (d)egrees and the (m)inutes. Divide minutes by 60.0 and add them to the degrees. Voila - you have your correct lat and lon.

Comment: And I have a question, where would you apply those formats in the code?